# KonvaJS strange response when trying to get an element

Tags: konvajs

I have a function that adds a lot of graphical stuff trough a loop, one thing that I add is a couple of rectangles, after they are created I put them in an array like this:

```
var rectB = new Konva.Rect({
    id: "rb"+i,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 240,
    height: 240,
    fill: '#00ff00',
    cornerRadius: 5,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowBlur: 5,
    shadowOffset: {x : 5, y : 5},
    shadowOpacity: 0.2
});

frameArray.push(rectB);
```

When I later try to access it with (just for testing) this simple code:

```
function imgClicked(ide){
    console.log("frameArray::"+frameArray[0].id);
}
```

I get this very strange response in the console:

```
"frameArray::function (){return arguments.length?(this[i](arguments[0]),this):this[a]()}"'
```

Does someone have an idea on what might go wrong here?

Best regards
/magnus

Comment: Sorry, silly me it works I just got confused with other errors and called for the ID the wrong way if use getId() it works.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a method. So you should use this:

```
console.log("frameArray::" + frameArray[0].id());
```